# Number of TIME_WAIT connections is less than expected

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming, time-wait

I have learned why TIME_WAIT is a good thing to have and want to ensure every of my connections stay in TIME_WAIT when it should. I wrote a small script (attached at the end) to perform the following things:

- Spawn a TCP listener on port 8000
- In a forever loop, connect to the listener, then shutdown the connection

  - The listener recv on the accepted connections to ensure they are always closed by the other end

What I expect is there are more and more `<random port> -> 8000` connections stays in TIME_WAIT state, until 60s when the first TIME_WAIT timeout, or the number of connections reaches 32768 which is the maximum number of concurrent TIME_WAIT connections according to `tcp` man page.

However, what I observed (through `netstat --tcp -n | grep TIME_WAIT | wc -l`) is that the number of TIME_WAIT connections keep stable around 14116, and never increase anymore. The number happens to equal (61000 - 32768) / 2 (the default ephemeral port range), making me can't help to build connection between them but has no clue.

The script

```rust
use std::net::SocketAddr;

use tokio::{
    io::AsyncReadExt,
    net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
    spawn,
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8000").await?;
    let listen_session = spawn(async move {
        let mut buf = [0; 1];
        loop {
            let (mut conn, _) = listener.accept().await?;
            conn.read(&mut buf).await?;
        }
    });
    let connect_session = async {
        for i in 0.. {
            let stream = TcpStream::connect(SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8000))).await?;
            println!("{i} {stream:?}");
            drop(stream)
        }
        Ok(())
    };
    tokio::select! {
        result = listen_session => result?,
        result = connect_session => result,
    }
}
```

By the way there's another problem about my understanding of TIME_WAIT. From [this well-known blog](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux) I learned that TIME_WAIT is mainly for preventing delayed packets to interfere with the following irrelevant connections with the same quad-tuple. My question is that why only the actively-closing side need to concern about this? Isn't that also possible for a delayed packet in the opposite direction arrives the passive-closing side?

Comment: "I have learned why TIME_WAIT is a good thing to have": it is. "... and want to ensure every of my connections stay in TIME_WAIT": why? That's the system's job. Having too *few* ports in TIME_WAIT is hardly something to worry about. The answer to your final question will be found in RFC 793, specifically the state diagram. The peer that receives the first FIN *knows* that its peer has closed the connection. The peer that first sends it doesn't, so it needs TIME_WAIT.

Comment: @user207421 I am exactly worrying that the system is not doing its job right: I want every connection to stay in TIME_WAIT for 1min, while it does not according to my observation, and I want to know what's going unexpectedly in the system. The rationale you discussed about protocol design corresponds to the second reason in the blog, which I agree, but not answering my question: knowing its peer has closed the connection does not necessarily gives confidence that slow reordered packets (e.g. the ones has been considered dropped and retransmitted) will not arrive anymore.

Comment: Well it does actually. See the RFC. You don’t need to worry about this matter. It was all sorted out several decades ago. And if you think your OS isn’t implementing TCP properly you are almost certainly wrong.

Comment: It's possible that there's some eager closing of sockets in TIME-WAIT state. The implementors may have decided that preventing running out of ports is more important than guarding against the unlikely case of lost FIN/ACK packets.

Comment: Not sure, but this might be related to the [`net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse`](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux#netipv4tcp_tw_reuse) configuration parameter,